# Lotie js animated background

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, lottie

Work with Lotie js and want use lotie animation like background, but animation covers all blocks. Z-index dont work. How to move the animation down so that other blocks are visible?

```css
.page {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position:absolute;
  z-index:-999;
}
.text {
z-index:10000;
position:absolute;
width:500px;
font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class='page'><lottie-player src="https://assets7.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_nee43fld.json"  background="transparent"  speed="1"  style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"    autoplay></lottie-player>
<div class="text">ddddddddddd</div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you see in the dev tools if the text is getting the z index property? Being enclosed in a parent div that has another index can mess that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try applying the z-index positioning to the player instead of its parent ".page" which also holds the ".text" element too.

```
lottie-player {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position:absolute;
  z-index:-999;
}
.text {
z-index:10000;
position:absolute;
width:500px;
font-size:30px;
}
```